# Framework para criar painéis de administração e dashboards

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de que me indicassem um Framework para criar painéis administrativos,se possível que já tenham dashboards inclusos.

Algumas pessoas já me indicaram Layouts prontos,mais eu gostaria de desenvolver o meu e conhecer a linguagem.

Tenho costume de usar Bootstrap, alguém poderia me indicar algum ?

Segue a imagem de um painel que gostei.

<kbd>[image: Painel]</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que você pode tentar trabalhar com alguns gratuitos e buscar entender como funciona o template, pois a maioria trabalha com a união de varias bibliotecas como o Bootstrap, Angular, Jquery e por ae vai.

Como você já tem mais costume com o bootstrap, acho que poderia dar uma olhada neste template: [AdminLTE](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE)

Além disso pode tentar construir o seu, utilizando o Material design. Veja alguns exemplos:

[design.google.com](http://design.google.com)

[www.getmdl.io](https://www.getmdl.io/)

Comment: Ótimo,Obrigado. Att,

Answer (score 3):

**A Melhor opção é comprar algum pronto.**

Existem diversos no mercado e muitos utilizam Bootstrap.
E com custos a partir de U$3,00 (R$ 12,00 por um template responsive) é preço de banana.

> OBS: Muitos vem o html puro, versão para php, ajax, .net, angular.js,
>   less, sass, etc.

Porém mesmo que não venha pronto em php fazer a migração de um html não será nenhuma tarefa difícil.

*Mesmo que você não utilize ele na integra, acaba te servindo como uma biblioteca de plugins, css, widget, etc. Pode ser bem útil comprar 2 ou 3 deles desmembrar e fazer o seu sistema com pedaços de vários.*

https://wrapbootstrap.com/themes/admin/page.1/sort.price/order.asc

Existem diversos outros sites, mas o único que recomendo é esse.

**Desvantagem**: A única desvantagem que posso encontrar é que muitos acabam abusando no uso de plugins então costumam ter milhares de .js juntos, porém nada que algumas horinhas você não consiga remover e deixar apenas o que deseja.

*Abaixo exemplo das versões de um layout comprado no link acima:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito interessante e inclusive já estou navegando no site,mais é que na verdade eu gostaria de eu mesmo estar criando um,mais não descartei sua ideia,achei bem interessante e bem acessível sim,obrigado pela dica.

Comment: compra 1, e desmembra ele 100%, entenda o que ele utilizou, quais plugins, vai acabar virando uma biblioteca de plugins para você, não precisa copiar 100% apenas vai utilizando 'pedaços' que achar interessante.

Comment: Ok,Obrigado pelas informações. Att,